# Which is the day the quarterly reports are released to the public - filling date or accepted date?

Tags: united-states, financial-statements, edgar

I'm looking at an API of financial reports, and I am noticing a "fillingDate" and an "acceptedDate".

```
"date" : "2019-09-28",
"symbol" : "AAPL",
"fillingDate" : "2019-10-31 00:00:00",
"acceptedDate" : "2019-10-30 18:12:36",
"period" : "FY",
"revenue" : 260174000000
```

Also, when looking at an earnings-calendar API, I see another date field:

```
date    "2019-10-30"
symbol  "AAPL"
eps 3.03
epsEstimated    2.8961268000000002
time    "amc"
revenue 64040000000
revenueEstimated    63929939186
```

My question is, which date field - *fillingDate* or *acceptedDate*, would be the date where the financial report is released to the public? I am assuming that the earnings-calendar date is an estimated release date because in many cases, the date in the earnings-calendar does not line up with fillingDate or acceptedDate.

Comment: `filling date` or `filing date`?? You seem to jump between two very different things.

Comment: Is that your way of telling me you found a spelling error?

Comment: What API is this? Could you give us a link to the documentation?

Comment: The API's documentation: https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/. The API has an embarrassing typo. It's supposed to be `filingDate` rather than `fillingDate`. The data comes from [Apple's 2019 10-K filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/0000320193-19-000119-index.htm) on EDGAR.

Comment: Wow I'm impressed. But, which is the day the QR is released to the public? ```Filing``` or ```Accepted```?

Comment: Your question asks about quarterly filings (Form 10-Q), but your examples show annual filings (Form 10-K).

Comment: I just grabbed a random example. It is also the case for many 10-Q. But either way, are neither of them the date that the report is released to the public? Regardless of K or Q?

Comment: Voted to reopen, crystal clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which is the day the quarterly reports are released to the public - filling (sic.) date or accepted date?

Answer: filing date.

---

### References

I did not know the answer to your question before I attempted to answer it. As such, I might have answered incorrectly. This is how I found the definitions of the terms used, and arrived at the answer:

**Definition of "filing date"**

According to the [EDGAR Filer Manual (Volume II)](https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/specifications/edgarfm-vol2-v54.pdf), section 10.1 *Filing Date of Electronically Transmitted Submissions*:

> If you begin direct transmission of a live submission after 5:30 P.M. Eastern time and the submission is accepted, it will have a filing date as of 6:00 A.M. the next business day. If you start direct transmission at or before 5:30 P.M., it will receive that day's filing date if it is accepted. [...]

This definition of "Filing Date" ultimately comes from [17 CFR § 232.13 (a) (2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/232.13). Note that there are a number of exceptions (e.g. [Final Rule:
Mandated Electronic Filing and Website Posting for Forms 3, 4 and 5](https://www.sec.gov/rules/final/33-8230.htm), etc.).

**Definition of "accepted"**

Appendix F: *GLOSSARY OF COMMONLY USED TERMS, ACRONYMS AND ABBREVIATIONS* of the filing manual defines "accepted":

> **ACCEPTANCE REVIEW** Procedural checks performed by EDGAR to determine whether a filing meets certain minimum filing requirements. The requirements may relate to the composition and completeness of the submission package, as well as to the particular type of filing being made.
>
> **ACCEPTED** The term that describes a filing that has successfully passed acceptance review.

In other words, when direct transmission finishes, the transmitted filing is automatically checked, and if the filing passes some automated tests, it is "accepted".

**What happens if the filing is submitted and accepted after 5:30 pm (but before 10 pm [SEC closing time])**

In section 3.2 *Electronic Form Types by Act* of the filing manual:

> Normally filings received after 5:30 P.M. Eastern time will receive a filing date of the next business day and will not be disseminated until the next business day.

Note that there are many exceptions.

Useful read: ["All About EDGAR" (and Exhibits)](https://wow.lw.com/Article/Index/186)