# which sec date is the date the form becomes public to people

Tags: sec, electronic-filing

there are 2 dates for each sec form: 1 is the filing date, the other is the accepted date.
I looked at those 2 questions:
[first question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131476/which-is-the-day-the-quarterly-reports-are-released-to-the-public-filling-date) and
[second question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/146248/what-is-the-difference-between-filing-date-and-accepted-date-in-edgar)

I need to understand:

1. at which date the original file is accesible to the public?
2. at which date the structured files (for example xml or txt with xml inside in form 4 ) is accesible to the public?

the first question (link) got an answer without votes, and also closed.
please make a clarification about it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "Filing Date" and "Accepted" date in EDGAR?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/146248/what-is-the-difference-between-filing-date-and-accepted-date-in-edgar)

Comment: no, that is the link i wrote about in my question.